# Indexing single page in google

Tags: google-search, google-search-platform

Let's say I have a site with multiple pages. One day I decide to index my page on google search, so anyone can find my page via google search. Another day I decide to add one more page e.g. some article. How can I invoke google, that I've added a new page and I would like to have it indexed immediately? I know that google crawls all indexed sites, but since there are a million of pages, it takes some time.

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Ask Google to crawl and index your URL:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6065812?hl=en

Comment: I've seen that answer. But isn't there any better solution? I don't need to reindex all pages I just want to add one more.